# How to dismiss/close an Angular Snackbar element from inside element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I currently have a `snackbar` element with a `mat-progress-bar` inside it. I'd like to close the `snackbar` element. My code currently looks like this.

```js
import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-progress-snackbar',
  template: `
  Progress:
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progress | async" *ngIf="progress !== undefined"></mat-progress-bar>`,
  styles: [`mat-progress-bar { margin-top: 5px;}`],
})
export class UploadProgressComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data) { }

  private started = false;
  public progress = this.data.uploadProgress.pipe(
    map(({ loaded, total }) => {
      if (loaded === undefined) {
        return !this.started ? 0 : 100;
      } else {
        this.started = true;
        return Math.round(loaded / (total || loaded) * 100);
      }
    },
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do the following to achieve this.

This `snack-bar` is like a `mat-dialog`.. you have to call the `dismiss()` on a `MatSnackBarRef`

DI `renderer` and `MatSnackBarRef`... you don't need renderer if you are going to dismiss some other way, this is just for demonstration purposes.

```
 @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data,
    private _snackRef: MatSnackBarRef<UploadProgressComponent>,
    private ren:Renderer2
```

If you wanted to dismiss on progress bar completing you could call `dismiss()` in that logic. I am going to dismiss on click.

Create click event listener in your `constructor`...

```
{ 
  setTimeout(()=>{
    let snackEl = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-snack-bar-container').item(0);
    ren.listen(snackEl, 'click', ()=>this.dismiss())
  })
```

create your `dismiss()`

```
  dismiss(){
    this._snackRef.dismiss();
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdyher?embed=1&file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts

Comment: using `document` is not SSR friendly.

Answer (score 12):

Marshal's solution is nice but requires a lot of effort.

The following solution is cleaner (No need to pass snack bar reference or listen to any dom event)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdyher-fctxtf?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-component-example.ts)

**Snackbar component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-progress-snackbar',
  template: `
  Hello :)
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="dismiss()">Dismiss</button>  
  `,

})
export class UploadProgressComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data) {}

  dismiss(){
    this.data.preClose(); //access preClose function when you want to close snackbar
  }
}
```

**Snackbar opener code:**

```
openSnackBar() {
    const snackBar = this.snackBar.openFromComponent(UploadProgressComponent, {
      data: {preClose: () => {snackBar.dismiss()} } //pass a function to be called when you want to close the snackbar
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

A good way to do this is leveraging Dependency Injection inside the custom Snack Bar component to create a snack bar reference. Then close the component using this reference.

CustomSnackBar.ts

```
constructor(
    private snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<GeneralSnackbarComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any
) { }

public dismiss(): void {
    this.snackBarRef.dismiss();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

CustomSnackBar.html

```
<button id="cancelBtn" mat-button (click)="dismiss()">
    Cancel
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this **Awesome Demo** on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7ggpc).

```js
export class PizzaPartyComponent {
  constructor(public snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<PizzaPartyComponent>,
  @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any){}
}
```

Use `snackBarRef.dismiss()` to close it.

If you face any flickering on showing snack bar, run it inside the Ngzone.

```js
constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, private zone: NgZone) {}

openSnackBar() {
  this.zone.run(()=>{
    this._snackBar.openFromComponent(PizzaPartyComponent, {
      data: this.message,
      duration: this.durationInSeconds * 1000,
    });  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article could help https://hoshcoding.com/courses/1/angular-material-snackbar.

Here you can see a complete example with angular material snackbar and how undo an action.

If you need the code here is the example:

```
openSnackbar(message, action) {
    let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(message, action);
    snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
      console.log("The snackbar is dismissed");
    });
    snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
      console.log("The snackbar action was triggered!");
    })
  }
```

Regards

Comment: I think is a good comment but not enough to give me -1 vote because it works perfectly.

Comment: The -1 was given because this answer has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: this answer helped in my case. +1